# UDP client based broadcast to all other available PCs

Tags: sockets, exception, tcp, udp

i have a pc connected to intranet. i assume there are n other PCs in the same intranet. Now, a udp server runs on all those n pcs. Now, my problem is i do not know the count of PCs with udp server in it. so i need to broadcast a message say 'abc' for which each pc with udp server will returns its own ip. now how do i broadcast my message 'abc' to all the n pcs available in my network.

Comment: You don't get a `BindException` when connecting a `DatagramSocket`. You get it when binding. You will need to post your code, and your exception, and its stack trace, but you've already described your problem incorrectly.

Comment: I am getting BindException when i am trying to create a DatagramSocket(port) as i have already mentioned above.

Comment: What you 'mentioned above' was 'when I *connect* to the same port as UDP', which is not correct, as I mentioned above. It's up there in black and white. And you still haven't posted your code, your exception, or your stack trace

Comment: i have changed the question. could you please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

In java

```
    ///SENDER SOCKET
     InetAddress group = null;
    try {
        group = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.49.255");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int port =1212;
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /////RECEIVE SOCKET
    DatagramSocket rsocket = null;
    try {
        rsocket = new DatagramSocket(1513);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        rsocket.setSoTimeout(2000);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now your sending and receiving

```
String message_to_send = "STRING_TO_SEND";
        byte[] ultimo = message_to_send.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket ultimopaquete = new DatagramPacket(ultimo, ultimo.length, group, port);
           try {
               socket.send(ultimopaquete);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

        /*AFTER DONE WAIT FOR SERVERS RESPONSE*/


        boolean ack = false;
        int countertoend=0;
        boolean cancelcheck = false;
        while (!ack) {

            byte[] recibir = new byte[5]; ////expected byte size
            DatagramPacket pkgrecibir = new DatagramPacket(recibir, 0, recibir.length);
            Log.d("UDP", "S: Receiving...");

            try {
                rsocket.receive(pkgrecibir);
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                Log.d("timeout","TIMEOUT EXCEPTION");
                if (mandarfaltan) {
                    try {
                        socket.send(ultimopaquete); /// send again if timeout until counter =7 to make sure 
                    } catch (IOException q) {
                        q.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (countertoend ==7)
                    {
                        Log.d("error","timeout error no response to done");
                        socket.close();
                        rsocket.close();
                        break;
                    }
                    cancelcheck = true;
                    countertoend++;

                } else {
                    Log.d("ACK", "TIMEOUT CANELING PASSING TO DONE");
                    socket.close();
                    rsocket.close();
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /////HERE YOU CAN OPTAIN ADDRESS OF RECEIVED PACKAGES 
            pkgrecibir.getAddress().getHostAddress();
            /////You can put the address on an array or something similar and you will get your results



        }
```

I imagina that whit other programing languages it is something similar to it. 
Regards